# Getting the original POST body from an Undertow route in Apache Camel

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I try to set up an HTTP endpoint where clients can send files. Given this route in Apache Camel:

```
    <route id="example-inbox">
        <from uri="undertow:http://localhost:8080/example-inbox" />
        <to uri="file:inbox/" />
    </route>
```

I get a file containing the string `hello` in the `inbox/` dir when I do

```
curl -i -X POST localhost:8080/example-inbox \
    -H "Content-Type: text/plain" \
    --data 'hello'
```

So it works fine. However, when I leave out the `Content-Type` header, I get an error:

```
 org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException: No body available of type: java.io.InputStream but has type: java.util.HashMap on: Message[98010B440702286-0000000000000000]. Caused by: No type converter available to convert from type: java.util.HashMap to the required type: java.io.InputStream. Exchange[98010B440702286-0000000000000000]. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException - No type converter available to convert from type: java.util.HashMap to the required type: java.io.InputStream]
```

I can avoid the error by converting the body to a string:

```
<convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String" />
```

Unfortunately, this converts the Hashmap to the string `{hello=}`.

How can I write the original POST body to the file regardless of any `Content-Type` header?

**Edit:**

Turns out Undertow will generate a HashMap because it assumes the content-type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. So I'd like to turn off any processing and just get the bytes as posted.

Answer (score 0):

The content "Content Type " header is important while dealing with data as it is given in docs. try this

String originalPostBody = exchange.getIn().getHeader("CamelHttpPostBody").toString();

or ;

String originalPostBody = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);

Comment: Hey thanks for your suggestions, I'm not sure how to apply them because I have to use XML. I tried with <setBody>
    <simple>${in.body}</simple>
  </setBody> but that lead to the same error "No type converter available to convert from type: java.util.HashMap to the required type: java.nio.ByteBuffer"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).